SQL Server 2022 migration: Method not found: Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSComponentMetaData100
I have an SSIS custom component which was developed sometime ago, we are migrating our databases and SSIS packages to SQL Server 2022 and I am getting the following error when trying to use the custom component:

Error: System.MissingMethodException: Method not found: 'Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.Wrapper.IDTSComponentMetaData100 Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.PipelineComponent.get_ComponentMetaData()'.
at SSIS.Components.ErrorColumName.ColumnName.PreExecute()
at Microsoft.SqlServer.Dts.Pipeline.ManagedComponentHost.HostPreExecute(IDTSManagedComponentWrapper100 wrapper)

I can see that the code uses
IDTSInput100 input = ComponentMetaData.InputCollection.GetObjectByID(inputID);
IDTSVirtualInput100 vInput = input.GetVirtualInput();

foreach (IDTSVirtualInputColumn100 vCol in vInput.VirtualInputColumnCollection)

but I am not clear on what has replaced this.
I appear to have IDTSComponentMetaData130 and similar, but I am concerned that this maybe because I have multiple versions of SQL on my development box, I cannot seem to find these references in SQL Server 2022 (only in 2019)
Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSPipelineWrap
Microsoft.SqlServer.DTSRuntimeWrap
Microsoft.SqlServer.PipelineHost

Looking for advice on SQL Server 2022 SSIS references and replacement calls to IDTSInput100 etc.
Thanks

IDTSComponentMetaData100 and friends are from SQL Server 2008. If you can't update the package version in Visual Studio you may have to craft it from scratch.

Hi, thankyou for your response. The code is a custom dataflow component, I can edit the code, but I am unclear to the supported methods for interacting with SSIS 2022. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/extending-packages-custom-objects/data-flow/creating-a-custom-data-flow-component?view=sql-server-ver16 appears to show that the '100'  interfaces are still current, but clicking on any of the namespaces takes me to a 2019 (or earlier article). I can't find anything that describes what interfaces are available for 2022?

The custom dataflow was put in place years ago when it was difficult to get the column name following an error. I know that I can now use componentMetaData130.GetIdentificationStringByID(Row.ErrorColumn).Substring(start, length); in a script task, but I have over 80 packages using the custom data flow component, so was hoping that an upgrade to this would be less painful than updating 80+ packages
